# How to sum array value and save in list

Tags: php

I have file of more than 7mb which has numbers which I put in and array below:

```
$allbarcodes = array(3117148100,3117148110,3117148120,3117148130,3118011010,3118011020,3118011060,3118011070,3118011080,3118011090,3118011100,3118011110,3118011120,3118011130,3118012010,3118012020,3118012060,3118012070,3118012080,3118012090,3118012100,3118012110,3118012120,3118012130,3118654010,3118654020,3118654060,3118654070,3118654080,3118654090,3118654100,3118654110,3118654120,3118654130,3118797010,3118797020,3118797060,3118797070,3118797080,3118797090,3118797100,3118797110,3118797120,3118797130,3118846010,3118846020,3118846060,3118846070,3118846080,3118846090,3118846100,3118846110,3118846120,3118846130,3119009010,3119009020,3119009060,3119009070,3119009080,3119009090,3119009100,3119009110,3119009120,3119009130,3119011010,3119011020,3119011060,3119011070,3119011080,3119011090,3119011100,3119011110,3119011120,3119011130,3119012010,3119012020,3119012060,3119012070);



for($i = 1; $i < count($allbarcodes); $i++)
    {
      try
      { 
        $sumOfnum = summation((int)$allbarcodes[$i]);
        $allbarcodes[$i] =  str_pad($allbarcodes[$i],10,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
        array_push($barcodeList,$sumOfnum.",".$allbarcodes[$i]);
      }
      catch(Exception $e)
      {
        echo "n Exception Caught", $e->getMessage(); 
      }
    }


function summation( $n)
{
    $m =0; $sum=0;

    while($n != 0)
    {
        $m = $n % 10;
        $sum = $sum + $m;
        $n = (int)$n/10;
    }
    return $sum;
}
```

I have about 300,000 numbers in a file and I need to sum all digits and create a file of sum value and save all numbers of that sum value in txt file. I have written below statement to create array:

```
array_push($barcodeList,$sumOfnum.",".(int)$allbarcodes[$i]);
```

For example: if number is "2399879110" its sum is "49" and this number should be written in 49.txt file.

For some numbers this code is working fine, but when numbers are more then this code not working properly and all numbers or various sum values like 23,35 or whatever started copying in 46.txt file.

Comment: same logic is working in c# code but not in php,

Comment: I'm not fully following the question however thought it would be worth pointing out the [foreach function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) within PHP. It's not a show stopper but helps neaten up code.

Comment: I'm not sure what your exact question is but maybe you have to increase your memory limit? try ini_set('memory_limit','32M'); in the script you run. This will increase the memory limit to 32MB.

Comment: I already set memory limit to 1024M

Comment: Can you provide more details on what you mean by "code not working properly". What exactly is it doing that is not correct?

Comment: I need to calculate sum of all digits in number and store it in array. for some numbers it is working fine but after some numbers sum is getting same i.e 46 and that number is repeatedly in array which is not exists in my array.

Comment: strange things can happen, if... you work on a 32 bit system and have integers bigger 4294967295 , on 64 bit 9223372036854775807 or your integers start with 0... https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.decoct.php ... e.g. $large_number = 9223372036854775808;
var_dump($large_number);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On 64 bit systems integers can be from -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807
>
> On 32 bit systems integers can be from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647

Your numbers seem to be greater than the 32 bit maximum, however, if you are reading them from a file they should come as strings, so don't cast them to `(int)`.  Also, it's quite a bit easier:

```
foreach($allbarcodes as $num) {
    $result[] = array_sum(str_split($num));
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/mXU9G) with output on 64 bit system.

As it looks like you want `sum,number`:

```
$result[] = array_sum(str_split($num)).",$num";
```

As for saving the number in a file named as the sum:

```
foreach($allbarcodes as $num) {
    file_put_contents("/path/to/".array_sum(str_split($num).".txt", $num);
}
```

If you want to write `sum,number` in the file then of course:

```
$sum = array_sum(str_split($num);
file_put_contents("/path/to/$sum.txt", "$sum,$num");
```